# SVG.js TextPath not aligned with path (Verticaly)

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm trying to place a text onto a path with svg.js

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Byteschmiede/ytz67egn/1/

```
var draw = SVG().addTo('body').size(500, 500)
draw.svg(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 4725 2363" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
            <path id="text1326" d="M2362.2,952.109C2548.36,773.615 2727.44,622.128 2899.46,497.647C3071.47,370.823 3216.39,286.272 3334.21,243.993C3452.02,201.721 3580.45,180.583 3719.47,180.58C4011.66,180.583 4247.3,278.051 4426.39,472.986C4607.82,665.577 4698.54,899.267 4698.55,1174.06C4698.54,1361.95 4658.48,1535.75 4578.37,1695.46C4498.25,1855.16 4383.97,1976.12 4235.52,2058.32C4089.42,2140.53 3920.94,2181.63 3730.08,2181.62C3482.66,2181.63 3265.87,2128.78 3079.72,2023.09C2895.92,1917.4 2656.75,1717.77 2362.2,1424.19C2055.87,1727.16 1811.99,1929.15 1630.55,2030.14C1449.11,2131.13 1238.21,2181.63 997.866,2181.62C691.537,2181.63 452.365,2086.51 280.351,1896.27C110.692,1706.03 25.862,1465.29 25.863,1174.06C25.862,901.616 115.404,667.926 294.489,472.986C475.929,278.051 712.744,180.583 1004.94,180.58C1146.32,180.583 1275.92,201.721 1393.74,243.993C1511.55,286.272 1655.29,370.823 1824.95,497.647C1996.97,622.128 2176.05,773.615 2362.2,952.109M2591.95,1170.53C2841.72,1417.14 3046.73,1585.07 3206.96,1674.32C3369.55,1761.22 3530.96,1804.67 3691.2,1804.67C3891.49,1804.67 4048.18,1745.95 4161.29,1628.52C4274.4,1508.74 4330.95,1364.3 4330.95,1195.19C4330.95,1009.65 4274.4,856.992 4161.29,737.208C4050.54,615.082 3903.27,554.017 3719.47,554.014C3615.79,554.017 3515.64,572.806 3419.04,610.382C3322.42,645.614 3206.96,709.027 3072.65,800.622C2938.33,889.873 2778.1,1013.18 2591.95,1170.53M2132.46,1170.53C1962.8,1027.27 1810.81,909.836 1676.5,818.237C1542.19,724.294 1424.37,657.357 1323.05,617.428C1221.72,577.503 1110.97,557.54 990.797,557.537C818.78,557.54 676.22,617.43 563.115,737.208C450.009,856.992 393.456,1009.65 393.457,1195.19C393.456,1324.37 422.911,1433.58 481.82,1522.83C540.729,1612.08 612.598,1681.37 697.428,1730.68C784.613,1780.01 893.006,1804.67 1022.61,1804.67C1192.27,1804.67 1357.21,1760.05 1517.45,1670.8C1677.68,1581.55 1882.68,1414.79 2132.46,1170.53" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:black;stroke-width:1px;"/>
            <path id="textCurve3" d="M294.489,472.986C475.929,278.051 712.744,180.583 1004.94,180.58C1146.32,180.583 1275.92,201.721 1393.74,243.993C1511.55,286.272 1655.29,370.823 1824.95,497.647" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:black;stroke-width:1px;"/>
            <path id="textCurve2" d="M2899.46,497.647C3071.47,370.823 3216.39,286.272 3334.21,243.993C3452.02,201.721 3580.45,180.583 3719.47,180.58C4011.66,180.583 4247.3,278.051 4426.39,472.986" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:black;stroke-width:1px;"/>
            <path id="textCurve1" d="M564.216,1310.73C609.732,1475.4 770.154,1619.22 909.116,1635.49C993.881,1645.42 1152.78,1644.6 1262.96,1605.82C1479.72,1529.53 1626.78,1408.31 1802.89,1258.49" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(177,0,52);stroke-width:1px;"/>
        </svg>
        `)

let textCurve1 = draw.find("#textCurve1")[0]
let textPath = textCurve1.text("Forever").font({
    size: textCurve1.height()
  })
  .attr({
    startOffset: '50%',
    'text-anchor': 'middle'
  })
  .fill({
    opacity: 0
  }).stroke({
    color: "#000",
    width: 1
  })
```

The red line is the target path.
The Text needs to follow the path.

As you can see, the text curve is correct but the placement is way to low on the y axis.

I'm not sure how to solve this, since there aren't much opportunities.
I tried attributes like *dominant-baseline* and *baseline-alignment* but nothing workend

[Here is a picture of the svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y1Jo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tspan with a dx attribute to move specific text up or down.

```js
const text = draw.text((text) => {
  text.tspan('Some Text').dx(10)
}).path(textCurve1)
```